# Please can somebody critique this stamp card codepen?

Tags: javascript, codepen

I have been searching high and low for a working example of a stamp card to use as a starting point for my own project.

I found this codepen:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/shaun21uk/pen/wbgNNb)

```
var i = 0

$(".points").click(function() {
  if (this.hasClass('points points-on')) {
    this.addClass("points-on");
    console.log("cje");
  } else {
    this.addClass("points-on");
    i = i + 1;
    console.log(i);
  }
});
```

Unfortunately the button does not seem to be working and I have very little javascript experience.

Could somebody help me disect what is going on here and how I could go about finishing up the work so that a circle fills up every time the button is pressed?

Thank you.

Comment: You should replace "this" by "$(this)"

Comment: updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bygZme), you should read about javascript and jquery as well.

Comment: @Durga - thanks but your codepen just reloads over and over.  I tried replacing this with $(this) but it made no difference.

Comment: The codepen works, as mentioned change `this` to `$(this)` in all the occurrence.

Comment: EDIT: Oh I see - you click the circle to highlight them, not the button! Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about `ADD POINTS` button?

Comment: Yes I was, like every button click lights up the next stamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css, and the jquery were both written weirdly. Below I have rewritten a the basic gist of what it was trying to do before - select stamps on click:

```js
var storedStamps = +prompt()
var stamps = $('.points')
for (var i = 0; i < storedStamps; i++) {
  stamps.eq(i).addClass('points-on')
}

var i = 0

$(".points").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('points-on')
  $('#points').text($(".points-on").length)
});

function addNextStamp() {
  var points = $(".points")
  for (var i in points) {
    if (!points.eq(i).hasClass('points-on')) {
      points.eq(i).addClass('points-on')
      $('#points').text($(".points-on").length)
      break;
    }
  }
}

function reset() {
  $('.points-on').removeClass('points-on')
  $('#points').text($(".points-on").length)
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.points {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.points-on {
  background-color: #CFFCFF;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.points {
  border-color: #AAEFDF;
}

.points:active {
  background-color: #AAEFDF;
  border-color: #CFFCFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="score">
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" id="addpoints" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="addNextStamp()">ADD POINTS</button>
    <button type="button" id="addpoints" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="reset()">RESET</button>
    <span style="color: white;"><span id="points">0</span> points</span>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT: Added counter

EDIT: Added functionality for button

EDIT: Added reset functionality.

> NOTE: You'll notice I copy and paste this line after every function: `$('#points').text($(".points-on").length)`
>
> This is only to update the points counter, which is necessary if the amount of stamps highlighted changes.

EDIT: Added stamps on load

Comment: Ah yes I see that is cleaner.  I assume with the i=i+1 calculation he was trying to build the functionality to click the "add points" button and fill in the next circle?

Comment: No, I think that was just to count how many buttons were active, but he didn't provide functionality to do the reverse - when deselecting a button. Ill make an edit showing you how many buttons are selected now.

Comment: Yea that's really nice, thanks.  So,thinking through the logic, to make the button fill the next empty circle: A starting variable would need to be set to points-on (0).  Each button click increases points-on +1.  In this case, wouldn't the html need to be using the same dynamic variable to understand which circle to fill? Like <li class='points-1'></li>?

Comment: You could just grab the list of of all the elements with the `points` class, check each element to see if it has the `points-on` class, if not add it to the first element, then add it. Ill try and make an edit in the next few mins 

Comment: @shaun21uk I added an edit, I think I did what you wanted.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much for sticking with me.  This is a great start for me, I will now work on resetting the circles and creating x amount of circles based on user input - all the best pal!

Comment: No problem, good luck If you ever need help, just let me know.

Comment: Hmmm, I actually thought I would be able to figure the reset part out quite easily but it's not to be.  I tried 
function resetPoints() {
  $(".points-on").length = 0
  }
but it isn't working....

Comment: No worries. Remember, that when you click on each of the buttons, the class `points-on` is added. You've got the right idea by selecting all the elements with `$(".points-on")`, and i see that you're trying to "remove" them by changing the length to 0. What you want to do instead, is use `removeClass('points-on`)`. This will make all the points turn off. I will add an edit now.

Comment: Wonderful, as with any new language, learning all of the individual syntax, and when to use them is daunting.  Thanks a lot Koban, you have been more than helpful!

Comment: Hi @Kobe sorry to bring you back to this but I have been trying to figure something out for quite a while now.  Every time my page is loaded the number of points is set to 0 with no stamps highlighted.  I will be loading the starting number dynamically from a db and sending that number back.
Which variable is counting the number of stamps on page load?  It looks like it should be $(".points-on") but I can't crack it.

Comment: You would use `$('.points-on').length` to get how many elements have that class.

Comment: Hmmm I tried that too - I hard-coded: 
var i = 0
$('.points-on').length = 2
but still on load all stamps are empty?

It sounds like I would need to "addClass('points-on')" 'x' number of times on page load?

Comment: Yep, you got it. Length is a read-only property, meaning you can't directly edit it. You would use `.length` to store how many elements were active in your database. You would get that variable and loop over x amount of elements and add that class. I'll add an edit now 

Comment: Then after adding a stamp I would add +1 to storedstamps and send that back to the db ready to be loaded next time.  Really nice work thanks for the support @Kobe

Comment: For something like this, I would recommend local storage, unless you really need it to be protected from deletion. Local storage will save a variable in the users browser, you can get it and modify it whenever you need to. The only drawback is that the user can clear their storage and you'd lose the data. I'll add an edit to my code to show you how you can use it

Comment: I can't use local storage on here so I'll explain it later if you want to use it

Comment: Oh man, I wasn't asking for your help with that; I havn't even tried myself yet :)  I was just explaining the reasoning behind my need for the variable. You're too kind :)  I plan on pulling the vairable from the user sql table into php - passing that into the script then sending it back and pushing back to the db

Comment: Hi @kobe any chance we could grab a chat room? I have 80% integrated this into my website and really need some fine tuning/help with the final touches.

Comment: @shaun21uk sure, I don't know when youre active, but ill join if you message me

Comment: Apparently I am unable due to my rep on Overflow, yet my rep on Exchange will allow me to talk.  I have entered a public chat room on there called Category Theory (just a random one) and mentioned you.  I cannot see a way to create a new room so that was my only option seemingly.....

Comment: thank you.  I need 20 rep to talk to you on Overflow.  Let me go try help some people and I will be right with you :)

Comment: @shaun21uk im back now